# iOS 5.0: MFMailComposeViewController Warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, ios5

Since I updated XCode for the new iOS 5.0 i get a warning in my MailComposer function.

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *pickerZap = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 pickerZap.mailComposeDelegate = self;
 // warning: Assigning to 'id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>' 
 // from incompatible type 'Infocontroller *'
```

What happend with the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate?
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can't really answer questions about iOS 5 without breaking the NDA.

But what this looks like is that your class (`Infocontroller`) doesn't formally implement the delegate protocol (`MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`), i.e.,

```
@class Infocontroller : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

Just implementing the methods isn't enough.

Comment: thanks i just forgot it, but now i'm wondering how it was working before i updated :)

Comment: They made things a lot more strict in the compiler now. You will get lots of these little warnings.